# How set debug sever host & port for device in emulator with what ip?

Tags: debugging, react-native, react-native-debugger

how Set debug server host & port for the device with what IP?
with ipv4 address not working 
in cmd type ipconfig but not working my project

[image]

this correct?

when reloading my project I have this error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this error 
and you should

first step: in terminal

> react-native start

two-step:

> reload in screen emulator